# Populate PDF fields from filtered data MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm have a database with some info and i made simple filter for it. I also made a class with a for each loop to populate pdf fields with that info. I'm trying to figure out how populate the same fields just with the filter data. For example i want to make PDF's with people of a specific city i filtered.

```
 //this is the filter.
public  ActionResult FilterReccords (string sucursal, string numPoliza, string numAgente, string numCertificado)
    {
        ViewBag.SUCUR = (from r in db.JUXLSY select r.SUCUR).Distinct();
        var filterRecord = from r in db.JUXLSY
                           orderby r.NOMBRE_AGENTE
                           where r.SUCUR == sucursal || sucursal == null || sucursal == ""
                           where r.PPOLIZ == numPoliza || numPoliza == null || numPoliza == ""
                           where r.AGENTE == numAgente || numAgente == null || numAgente == ""

                           select r;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numPoliza) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numAgente))
        {
            filterRecord = filterRecord.Where(r => r.PPOLIZ.Contains(numPoliza));
        }

        return View(filterRecord);

    }
```

This is the class that populate the fields. For now it populates the fields and creates a PDF for all the entries in the Database. I need it to populate and create a PDF from only the filtered data.

```
public void CreateVoucher()
    {
        Aspose.Pdf.License license = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
        license.SetLicense("Aspose.Pdf.lic");
        Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form pdfForm = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form();
        var output = Server.MapPath("/PrintingOutput/");

        using (var db = new db_VouchersEntities())
        {

            var voucher = db.JUXLSY.ToList();

            foreach (var vouch in voucher)
            {

                pdfForm.BindPdf(Server.MapPath("/VoucherTemplate/VoucherCertificateTemplateForm.pdf"));
                pdfForm.FillField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].AseguradoraTxt[0]", vouch.SUCUR);

                if (Directory.Exists(output) == false)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(output);
                    pdfForm.FlattenAllFields();
                    pdfForm.Save(output + vouch.SUCUR.ToString().Trim() + '_' + vouch.NOMBRE_AGENTE.ToString().Trim() + '_' + vouch.PCERNO.ToString().Trim() + ".pdf");
                }
                else
                {
                    pdfForm.FlattenAllFields();
                    pdfForm.Save(output + vouch.SUCUR.ToString().Trim() + '_' + vouch.NOMBRE_AGENTE.ToString().Trim() + '_' + vouch.PCERNO.ToString().Trim() + ".pdf");
                }

            }

        }




    }
```

Do i just add the if statement on the FilterRecords action method? But how do i Access the r in where if the r is on the other method

```
    public ActionResult FilterRecords(string sucursal, string numPoliza, 
     string numAgente, string numCertificado)
{
      var filteredRecords = RequestRecords(sucursal, ...);
      // store your filter parameters in a session
      Session["sucursal"] = sucursal;

//filter to be display to the user               
       if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sucursal))
        {
            filterRecord = filterRecord.Where(r => r.SUCUR.Contains(sucursal));
        }


      return View(filteredRecords);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that your CreateVoucher() method is invoked later on, after results of FilterRecord are displayed on your website.
If this is true, I suggest, that you store your filter parameters in the user session and pass it to your CreateVoucher() method, when the user requests it.

Instead of performing a db query within your CreateVoucher(), you'd better call a special method - e.g. RequestRecords(...) - in both, Action and CreateVoucher() which do all the data query stuff.

```
private IEnumerable<string> RequestRecords(string sucursal, string numPoliza, string numAgente, string numCertificado) 
{
    var filterRecord = (from r in db.JUXLSY
                       orderby r.NOMBRE_AGENTE
                       where r.SUCUR == sucursal || sucursal == null || sucursal == ""
                       where r.PPOLIZ == numPoliza || numPoliza == null || numPoliza == ""
                       where r.AGENTE == numAgente || numAgente == null || numAgente == ""
                       select r).ToList();
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sucursal))
    {
        filterRecord = filterRecord.Where(r => r.SUCUR.Contains(sucursal));
    }

    return filteredRecord;
}

public ActionResult FilterRecords(string sucursal, string numPoliza, string numAgente, string numCertificado)
{
      var filteredRecords = RequestRecords(sucursal, ...);
      // store your filter parameters in a session
      Session["sucursal"] = sucursal;
      ...

      return View(filteredRecords);
}

public void CreateVoucher(string sucursal, string numPoliza, string numAgente, string numCertificado)
{
     var filteredRecords = RequestRecords(sucursal, ...);
     foreach( var record in filteredRecords)
     {
          // your pdf creation stuff 
     }
}
```

Comment: they are 2 separete buttons, one calls the FilterReccords and shows the filtered record, the other one calls the the create voucher and prints out the PDF's. That sounds great thanks. Could you clarify some points though, I'm just starting to work MVC. where you put "TypeOfYourRecords" they are all strings, when i create the special method and define it as string. it gives me a messaege with "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryble to string" . what sould i put there? Also on the FilterRecord method do i just repete what you added for all the parameters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, you tried to return the Query itself, which caused the "Cannot implicitly convert type " error. So please recognize the round brackets around the query and the .ToList() call which executes the query against the db and returns a list (of strings in your case). I edit my post with the full signature of all methods, so i hope it's clearer now.

Comment: sorry, i also asumed that you use a kind of model which is stored in your db. strings are fine, so i edit the signature to return a list of strings

Comment: Thank you so much. 2 last things , how can i make the button call the RequestRecords to do the queries and then that same button call the FilterRecords action to display the filtered list. And how do I access the session variable to do the filter? do i just add the if statement to the FileterRecords action like this:

Comment: i added the last code block as the example for the question above

Comment: Hi Cordero, i can't answer your first action because it depends on so many things, the second question is easy: put the `if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sucursal))` part in your RequestRecords method (see my edited answer). Cheers.